# Using CEditCtrl in CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

In a dialog I am displaying CMFCTabctrl using below code.

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(rect);
// Create tabs window:
m_ctrlTab.Create(Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_ONENOTE, rect, this, 1, CMFCBaseTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);
m_ctrlTab.AutoDestroyWindow();
```

And I am attaching a child modeless dialog to tabctrl using below code. This dialog has a edit control which allows only numbers.

```
CSampleDlg* p = new CSampleDlg(&m_ctrlTab);
 m_ctrlTab.AddTab(p,"DataBlock1");
```

When typing non digit letters in the edit control , by default user will get "Unacceptable character" tooltip.But on  tooltip is getting displayed I am getting grey shade.when typing more than one non digit letter I am facing this problem.

[image]

I uploaded my demo code here.
[code](https://aspiresysinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/sujitha_ramamoorthy_aspiresys_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1d1db33ac43aa4ddca752701783aacdd5&authkey=AZ3m8YHi9ZZNvyrzLj3ThtU)

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think it is because you set the `Number` property of your edit to `True`. On the resources.

Comment: The problem is not about getting the warning "Unaacceptable character".My problem is getting grey shade in the editctrl when tooltip is getting displayed.This is only happening when using CMFCTabCtrl.